# MPI: Values after scattering are corrupted

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I want to create only with process 0 a matrix with random values.
After creating it I scattered of the values to different processes.
I have the problem, that I receive corrupted values like

> 1980714952
>
> 32716
>
> -672521120
>
> -672521856
>
> 21858
>
> -310078720
>
> 21858
>
> 0
>
> 0

How can scatter a matrix created by process 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 3

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    int rank;
    int size;
    
    int aa[N];
    int a[N][N];
    
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    
    if (rank = 0)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {

                    a[i][j] = (rand() % 5);
            }
        }
        

    }
    
    MPI_Scatter(a, N*N/size, MPI_INT, aa, N*N/size, MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {

            printf("%d\n", aa[x]);  
    }
        
        
    

    MPI_Finalize();


}


float maxValue(float* array, int _size)
{
    float v = 0.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] >= v)
        {
            v = array[i];
        }   
    }
    
    return v;
}
```

Comment: do you guarantee `N*N/size <= N` ?

Comment: How can I guarantee that  N*N/size <= N?  I think the buffersize is not correctly.

Comment: If I removed the if condition for rank 0 the values seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `N*N/size` definition. You define `N` as `3` and if the number of processes exceeds `3`, say take number of processes as `4`, then `N*N/Size` will be `9/4` and hence the value will be `2`. So `2` elements will only be scattered by `rank 0` to all the processes. As a result, at the end, all the processes will print `N` (Here `3`) values but `2` values are only received from rank `0` and the third one will be garbage value. Similarly, this behaviour happens for other number of processes greater than `N`.

You can test this by  `a[i][j] = (rand() % 5);` changing this to  `a[i][j] = i;` and start with number of processes as 3. It will work as expected. If you increase the size of processes you can see that garbage values will be printed with the output.

Also `if (rank = 0)` should be if `(rank == 0)`.

To answer the question in comment:

To send `N` `(x,y)` values to `P` processes, the changes will be.

```
    #define N 9 // this value must be divisible by P number of processes, because scatter is used for distributing uniform size. for 9 processes, the N can be any multiple of 9
    int aa[2*N/size]; // the receiving process only needs N/size * 2 values
    int a[N][2]; // since 2 values for each N
    MPI_Scatter(a, N*2/size, MPI_INT, aa, N*2/size, MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for (int x = 0; x < N*2/size; x++) // each processes print its local values
      {
        printf("rank %d, %d\n", rank,aa[x]);
      }
```

In short: To equally distribute a pair of `N` (x,y) values among `P` processes using `scatter`, `N` should be divisible by `P`. Otherwise you have to use `scatterv`

Comment: Which size must be choosen, if I want to distribute the xy-values to all 9 processes?

Comment: So if you want to distribute, n out of N (x,y) values across P processes, what I would do is, first I will define N  (eg: 18), then i declare array with int a[N][2]  (i used 2 because i want to distribute it in pairs (x,y)), inside the loop where I define the array value, in second loop i will use the condition j<2 instead of N. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you, j23. I also experimented around with the MPI scatter and gather. I must found out a better way for scattering and gathering a 3D matrix, because of an exercise for the exam. I also had publish 2 hours ago another question which is more related to the exercise I must understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63919764/mpi-distributed-3d-matrix-and-conjoined-2d-matrix . The other question is still unanswered except a few comments.