# MPI: Distributed 3D matrix and conjoined 2D matrix

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Write a MPI program in which a 3-dimensional matrix (xyz) is created
> on node 0 The matrix is distributed equally to all nodes. Each node
> determines the maximum z-value for each xy-coordinate and stores this
> in a 2-dimensional matrix. The individual partial solutions should
> finally can be joined at node 0

I am working with 3 processes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 3

 

int maxValue(int* array, int _size);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    int rank;
    int size;
    
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    
    int matrix2D[N][N];
    int xy[N][N];
    int c[N][N];
    
    int matrix3D[N][N][N] =   {
                    {
                        {1, 1, 1}, 
                        {2, 2, 2}, 
                        {3, 3, 3}
                    },
                    
                    {
                        {4, 4, 4}, 
                        {5, 5, 5}, 
                        {6, 6, 6}
                    },
                    
                    {
                        {7, 7, 7}, 
                        {8, 8, 8}, 
                        {9, 16, 9}
                    }
                };
                

    

    

    MPI_Scatter(matrix3D, N*N*N/size, MPI_INT, xy, N*N*N/size, MPI_INT, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
        {

            matrix2D[x][y] = maxValue(xy[x], N);

            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Gather(matrix2D, N*N, MPI_INT, c, N*N, MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    

    

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            {

                    printf("%d, ", matrix2D[x][y]);
            
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    

}


int maxValue(int* array, int _size)
{
    int v = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] >= v)
        {
            v = array[i];
        }   
    }
    
    return v;
}
```

As you can see the matrix has some maximum values. I'm not satisfied with my result, because my  output is:

```
1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3,
```

<s>and I have the feeling my exercise is incomplete.</s>
If I create the matrix inside a if (rank == 0)-clause the values will be corrupted.
I have no idea, with sending and receiving sizes I must give to the scatter and gather functions.

Comment: _I have the feeling my exercise is incomplete..._  Why do you have this feeling.  Can you put it in more concrete terms?  If you cannot, then clarification from your book, or instructor is needed.

Comment: The exercise says that the matrix must be created by the process (node) 0. I'm not sure if I have to put the matrix creation inside a if-clause with rank == 0. And the output should contain a 16, because it's a maxValue from the z-coordinate.

Comment: `MPI_Scatter()` might cause some buffer overflow, unless you are making some assumptions on the number of MPI tasks (and in that case, add some `if` or `assert()` to make them clear). `MPI_Gather()` cause a buffer overflow if you run more than one MPI task.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you. These are very important information.